# How to create a DataFrame from two lists with multiple operations

Tags: python, dataframe

I have two lists,

```
A=[a1, a2, a3, a4]
B=[b1, b2, b3, b4]
```

I want to convert this to a dataframe C, where

```
C1      C2     C3     C4
a1*b1    0      0      0
a1*b2  a2*b1    0      0
a1*b3  a2*b2  a3*b1    0
a1*b4  a2*b3  a3*b2  a4*b1
```

Comment: Please include your effort into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

A = np.array(A)
B = np.array(B)

columns = ["C"+str(i) for i in range(1,len(A)+1)]

rows = []
for row in range(0,len(A)):
    if row == 0:
        rows += [A[row]*B]
    else:
        rows += [A[row]*np.array([0]*row + B[:-row].tolist())]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(rows).T, columns=columns)
```